# WPF MVVM Combobox IsEditable="True"

Tags: wpf

I have this issue, I must use IsEditable="True" in a combobox but when I select an item I get in the text "Travel_order.Model", while if i remove IsEditable="True" I get an item. (see the picture)
How can i resolved ?

this is the code.

```
            <ComboBox x:Name="Cmb_Uti" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding User_Utilizzatore, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectUser_Utilizzatore, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      IsEditable="True"                          

                      Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"   
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="5,17,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DescUtente, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ComboBox.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF0A0A0A" Opacity="0.6"/>
                </ComboBox.Effect>
            </ComboBox>


    Public Property User_Utilizzatore As ObservableCollection(Of Model_User_Utilizzatore)
    Private _SelectUser_Utilizzatore As Model_User_Utilizzatore
    Public Property SelectUser_Utilizzatore As Model_User_Utilizzatore
        Get
            Return _SelectUser_Utilizzatore
        End Get
        Set(value As Model_User_Utilizzatore)
            _SelectUser_Utilizzatore = value
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectUser_Utilizzatore")
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: "(see the picture)" what pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to define ItemTemplate as textBlock. When you do that and add IsEditable = true, the item will become a textbox.
To Avoid this, just use DisplayMemberPath:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="Cmb_Uti" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding User_Utilizzatore, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectedValuePath="Value"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectUser_Utilizzatore, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                IsEditable="True"           
                DisplayMemberPath="DescUtente"               
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"   
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="5,17,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176">
        <ComboBox.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF0A0A0A" Opacity="0.6"/>
        </ComboBox.Effect>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help.
You are very kind, can I ask you another question ?
I wanted to store the typed text in the combobox, what should I write in the code behind ?

something like this ??
.
.

messagebox.show(SelectUser_Utilizzatore.DescUtente) (<--in that way I see the items in the combo but i can't see what the user typed)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Found a neat little workaround: You can bind the IsEditable property to a bool and switch it to false when the bound SelectedItem is set. Works just as wanted...

```
     <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding YourSource}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem}" 
            Text="Please select..." 
            IsEditable="{Binding ComboBoxEditable}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ToWhatever}"/> 
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ComboBox>
```

and the code:

```
     private Object _YourSelectedItem;
     public Object YourSelectedItem { get { return _YourSelectedItem; } set { YourSelectedItem = value); ComboBoxEditable = false;  } }

     private Boolean _ComboBoxEditable;
     public Boolean ComboBoxEditable { get { return _ComboBoxEditable; } set { _ComboBoxEditable = value); } }
```