# ComboBoxItems displaying object instead of property when selected

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, combobox

I have encountered the following problem:

**ISSUE:** ComboBoxItems displaying perfectly but displaying whole object when items are selected.

**1. Clicking on comboBox:** ComboBoxItems displaying perfectly

[image]

**2. One ComboBoxitem is selected:** Whole Entity Framework object is displayed instead of just item name.

[image]

**Here is an example of what is displayed when a ComboBoxItem is selected:**
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.tblContainer_C0BE4F13C798ED380A1E249BFB338D265E97D4F4C7A880C5D813102738561025

**Desired result:** Bout verre bouchon emery

**This is a minified version of my code:**

```
<ComboBox IsEditable = "True" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsContainer}" SelectedValuePath="ContainerID">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        Width="100"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{Binding ContainerName}" 
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Here is the list to which the ComboBox binds:

```
public virtual List<tblContainer> ProductsContainer { get { return db.tblContainer.ToList(); } }
```

**ProductsContainer** has the attributes: **ContainerID** and **ContainerName**

Comment: add the code of the class tblContainer or at least  the minimal code needed for your example to work.

Comment: You probably don't want to set IsEditable to true. The ItemTemplate is not applied then. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27636357/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work when `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"`and  `TextSearch.TextPath="ContainerName"` is used.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsContainer}" SelectedValuePath="ContainerID" 
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="ContainerName">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    FontSize="15"
                    Width="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding ContainerName}" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help! Also, I just tried removing IsEditable="True" from my original code a few minutes ago and it works as well